# Calculate sum of converged series: $1/4 \times x + 4/9 \times x^2 + 9/16 \times x^3...$ where $x \in (0,1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to calculate the sum of converged series: 
$$\frac{1}{4}x + \frac{4}{9}x^2 + \frac{9}{16}x^3+\ldots$$
 where $x \in (0,1)$. Really appreciate any help

Comment: The solution doesn't seem doable by hand... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5Bk%5E2x%5Ek%2F(k%2B1)%5E2,k,1,infty%5D

Comment: For $s(x)$ I got the following equation: $s(x)+3xs'(x)+xs''(x)=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}.$

Comment: @Karn Watcharasupat You can't do it without the non-elementary function ${\rm Li}_2(x)$, but if you know it, you can calculate the representation by hand.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I see. I just finished Junior College in Singapore haha so I don't really know these special functions. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{r^2}{(r+1)^2}x^r=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{(r+1-1)^2}{(r+1)^2}x^r=\sum_{r=1}^\infty x^r-\dfrac1x\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}+\dfrac1x\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^{r+1}}{(r+1)^2}$$

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}=-\ln(1-x)-x$$

As $$\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac{x^{r+1}}{(r+1)^2}\right)}{dx}=\dfrac{x^r}{r+1}$$

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^{r+1}}{(r+1)^2}=\int\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^r}{r+1}dx=-\int\dfrac{\ln(1-x)+x}x\ dx$$